# Make a JFormattedTextField behave like ATM input

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield, number-formatting

I would like to know if there is anyway to make a JformattedTextField or jtextField behave like an atm money input. With that I mean you enter from the right to left, say you enter 10 you need to press 2 more 0's so that it will be 10.00 . The program enters the decimal point automatically as he types from right to left? If the 2 0's are not entered it will just be .10 .  Is this possible?  How would that be returned to me if I want to use that string to do calculations on then? I tried the abstract formatter but this doesn't work so nicely. I want to use this for input for the amount of money received by a customer. But make it idiot proof.

Comment: I think you can attach listener to the textfield and do whatever functionality you would like to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This forces the user to always enter text from the right no matter where the caret is positioned. All previous characters are shifted left as a new character is inserted. Formatting will be applied based on your formatter:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class ABMTextField extends JTextField
{
    private DecimalFormat format;
    private String decimal;

    public ABMTextField(DecimalFormat format)
    {
        this.format = format;

        decimal = Character.toString( format.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator() );

        setColumns( format.toPattern().length() );
        setHorizontalAlignment(JFormattedTextField.TRAILING);

        setText( format.format(0.0) );

        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument)getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter( new ABMFilter() );
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text)
    {
        Number number = format.parse(text, new ParsePosition(0));

        if (number != null)
            super.setText( text );
    }

    public class ABMFilter extends DocumentFilter
    {
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException
        {
            replace(fb, offs, 0, str, a);
        }

        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException
        {
            if (".0123456789".contains(str))
            {
                Document doc = fb.getDocument();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()) );

                int decimalOffset = sb.indexOf( decimal );

                if (decimalOffset != -1)
                {
                    sb.deleteCharAt(decimalOffset);
                    sb.insert(decimalOffset + 1, decimal);
                }

                sb.append(str);

                try
                {
                    String text = format.format( format.parse( sb.toString() ) );
                    super.replace(fb, 0, doc.getLength(), text, a);
                }
                catch(ParseException e) {}
            }
            else
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }

        public void remove(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
            throws BadLocationException
        {
            Document doc = fb.getDocument();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()) );

            int decimalOffset = sb.indexOf( decimal );

            if (decimalOffset != -1)
            {
                sb.deleteCharAt(decimalOffset);
                sb.insert(decimalOffset - 1, decimal);
            }

            sb.deleteCharAt( sb.length() - 1) ;

            try
            {
                String text = format.format( format.parse( sb.toString() ) );
                super.replace(fb, 0, doc.getLength(), text, null);
            }
            catch(ParseException e) {}
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
        ABMTextField abm = new ABMTextField( format );

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add( abm );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ABMTextField");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> How would that be returned to me if I want to use that string to do calculations on then?

You would need to create a method, maybe getValue() that would use the format.parse(...) method to return an actual number.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [How to use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), in particular [Using MaskFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#maskformatter).

Something like...

```
MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("##.##");
JFormattedTextField field = JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```

for example may help.

**Simple example**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class TestFormattedTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFormattedTextField();
    }

    public TestFormattedTextField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField();
                    MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("##.##");
                    formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
                    field.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(formatter));

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                    frame.add(field);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (ParseException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }        
}
```

**Additional Example**

Now, I realise that the previous example doesn't meet your exact needs (as you described them), it is a simple solution, I've also added a `DocumentFilter` example...

[image]

Which will output...

```
Value = 0.1
Value = $0.10
```

[image]

Which will output

```
Value = 10.0
Value = $10.00
```

Code...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class TestFormattedTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFormattedTextField();
    }

    public TestFormattedTextField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                MoneyField field = new MoneyField();
                field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        MoneyField field = (MoneyField) e.getSource();
                        double value = field.getValue();
                        System.out.println("Value = " + value);
                        System.out.println("Value = " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(value));
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(field);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MoneyField extends JTextField {

        public MoneyField() {
            setColumns(5);
            setHorizontalAlignment(RIGHT);
            ((AbstractDocument) getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new Filter());
        }

        public double getValue() {

            String text = getText();
            if (!text.contains(".")) {
                text = "0." + text;
            }

            return Double.parseDouble(text);

        }

        protected class Filter extends DocumentFilter {

            protected String getNumbers(String text) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.length());
                for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
                    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                        sb.append(c);
                    }
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                if (length > 0) {
                    fb.remove(offset, length);
                }
                insertString(fb, offset, text, attrs);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
                text = getNumbers(text);
                if (text.length() > 0) {
                    int docLength = fb.getDocument().getLength();
                    if (docLength == 2) {
                        text = "." + text;
                    }
                    if (docLength + text.length() < 6) {
                        super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
                if (offset == 3) {
                    offset = 2;
                    length = 2;
                }
                super.remove(fb, offset, length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check out [DocumentFilter examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details

Comment: +1, I see we were both working on a DocumentFilter approach which I think is the way to go.

Comment: @camickr I Still think the `JFormattedTextField` is simpler approach, but the `DocumentFilter` will more closely meet the OP requirements...

Answer (score 1):

Use `DocumentFilter` for the JTextField and override the appropriate method to handle the number formatting. Also it will be nice if you can post what you have tried and 'doesn't work'.

Comment: `DocumentListener` isn't an appropriate choice for "filtering" input into the document.  Changes have already being made to the document by the time `DocumentListener` is called and any modifications within the listener will cause an exception to be thrown

Comment: @MadProgrammer - You are right. I was referring to DocumentFilter and typed DocumentListener :-)

Comment: Don't you love it when your fingers do one thing and brain does another :P

Comment: I have tried to create a regex for it . I have tried the making an input mask, the input mask work until the number becomes bigger than 99.99 . With the Regular expression using the matcher I have found it was way to buggy when it had to check on the key pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I am a few years late to replying to this question, however, I would like to suggest an improvement over the code written by camickr. His code is really good, but I have modified it a bit to have 3 additional methods:

```
setLong() - sets a value programmatically to the text field;
getLong() - returns a value programmatically from the text field;
clearLong() - programmatically sets value to 0.00;
```

JCurrencyField class:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.ParsePosition;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

/**
 * @apiNote This currency field class is limited by long's capabilities. It is
 *          best to use BigDecimals when dealing with money values due to higher
 *          precision and longer maximal value
 */
public class JCurrencyField extends JTextField {
    // ----------------------- CLASS RELATED LOGIC

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
    private String decimal;

    /**
     * This class is responsible for accepting long value input. It has an ATM like
     * behavior.
     * 
     * @apiNote
     *          <h1>WARNING:</h1> Do not use {@link #setText(String)}.<br>
     *          <br>
     *          Use:
     *          <ul>
     *          <li>{@link #setLong(long)};</li>
     *          <li>{@link #clearLong()};</li>
     *          <li>{@link #getLong()}</li>
     *          </ul>
     *          methods instead.
     */
    public JCurrencyField() {
        decimal = Character.toString(format.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator());

        setColumns(format.toPattern().length());
        setHorizontalAlignment(JFormattedTextField.TRAILING);

        setText(format.format(0.00));

        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument) getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter(new ATMFilter());
    }
    
    /**
     * This class is responsible for accepting long value input. It has an ATM like
     * behavior.
     * 
     * @apiNote
     *          <h1>WARNING:</h1> Do not use {@link #setText(String)}.<br>
     *          <br>
     *          Use:
     *          <ul>
     *          <li>{@link #setLong(long)};</li>
     *          <li>{@link #clearLong()};</li>
     *          <li>{@link #getLong()}</li>
     *          </ul>
     *          methods instead.
     *
     * @param value the value
     */
    public JCurrencyField(long value) {
        decimal = Character.toString(format.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator());

        setColumns(format.toPattern().length());
        setHorizontalAlignment(JFormattedTextField.TRAILING);

        setText(format.format(0.00));

        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument) getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter(new ATMFilter());
        
        setLong(value);
    }

    /**
     * @apiNote This method is overriden, it sets only one char/letter at a time.
     *
     * @apiNote DO NOT USE THIS METHOD TO SET A VALUE TO THIS JCurrencyField. Use
     *          {@link #setLong(long)}; {@link #clearLong()}; {@link #getLong()}
     *          methods instead.
     * @param text the new text
     */
    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        // Delete value
        if (text.equals("")) {
            super.setText(text);
        }

        // Add 1 char of number
        Number number = format.parse(text, new ParsePosition(0));

        if (number != null)
            super.setText(text);
    }

    /**
     * This class changes the behavior of {@link JTextField}.
     * <ul>
     * <li>When method {@link JTextField#setText(String)} is called it will append
     * only one char/letter at the end of the value</li>
     * <li>When backspace/delete is pressed, only the last char/letter at the of the
     * value will be deleted</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    public class ATMFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        /**
         * Inserts a string.
         *
         * @param fb   the fb
         * @param offs the offs
         * @param str  the str
         * @param a    the a
         * @throws BadLocationException the bad location exception
         */
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
            replace(fb, offs, 0, str, a);
        }

        /**
         * Adds one char at the right end of this component.
         *
         * @param fb     the fb
         * @param offs   the offs
         * @param length the length
         * @param str    the str
         * @param a      the a
         * @throws BadLocationException the bad location exception
         */
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a)
                throws BadLocationException {
            Document doc = fb.getDocument();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));

            // Dealing with single char input
            if (".0123456789".contains(str)) {
                int decimalOffset = sb.indexOf(decimal);

                if (decimalOffset != -1) {
                    sb.deleteCharAt(decimalOffset);
                    sb.insert(decimalOffset + 1, decimal);
                }

                sb.append(str);

                try {
                    String text = format.format(format.parse(sb.toString()));
                    super.replace(fb, 0, doc.getLength(), text, a);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }
            } else
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }

        /**
         * Removes one char from the right end.
         *
         * @param fb     the fb
         * @param offset the offset
         * @param length the length
         * @throws BadLocationException the bad location exception
         */
        public void remove(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
            Document doc = fb.getDocument();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));

            int decimalOffset = sb.indexOf(decimal);

            if (decimalOffset != -1) {
                sb.deleteCharAt(decimalOffset);
                sb.insert(decimalOffset - 1, decimal);
            }

            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);

            try {
                String text = format.format(format.parse(sb.toString()));
                super.replace(fb, 0, doc.getLength(), text, null);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    // ----------------------- METHOD TO BE USED BY PROGRAMMER TO MODIFY THE VALUE

    /**
     * Clears Value from this {@link JCurrencyField}.
     */
    public void clearLong() {
        try {
            String valueStr = String.valueOf(getLong());
            int length = valueStr.length();

            for (int iChar = 0; iChar < length; iChar++) {
                getDocument().remove(0, 0);
            }

        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets Value for this {@link JCurrencyField}.
     *
     * @param value the new long
     */
    public void setLong(long value) {
        // Clear old value
        clearLong();
        
        // Set new value
        String valueStr = String.valueOf(value);
        int length = valueStr.length();

        for (int iChar = 0; iChar < length; iChar++) {
            setText(valueStr.substring(iChar, iChar + 1));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets value from this {@link JCurrencyField}.
     *
     * @return the long
     */
    public long getLong() {
        // Remove white spaces of any kind, remove . and , -> return only numbers
        String s = getText().replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace(" ", "").replace("\\s", "").replaceAll("\u00a0",
                "");
        s = s.trim();

        return Long.valueOf(s);
    }
}
```

**Note:**
In my modified code I use long as the basis of the currency value instead of String. Basically I assume that money value is a long by doing so.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I do apologies, but in my sincere opinion I think you consider my well documented answer as unclear just because you are a bot and not a real human being.